# How to refer 'this' keyword in React Stateless Component

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

Am trying to create a React Stateless Components for input range day picker using library [day-picker](http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/input-from-to).

If I try to convert the Stateful Component to Stateless, the `this` keyword is not accessible, since Stateless components doesn't have the scope for `this`.

Am very new to React and Hooks and gave my best to resolve, but somehow failed to resolve the problem, this is what I was trying.

Problem - Day picker range input is not working as expected. Always the calendar show start with current month. But somehow it is starting from last year.

[Actual Code](http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/input-from-to)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DayPickerInput from 'react-day-picker/DayPickerInput';
import moment from 'moment';
import { formatDate, parseDate } from 'react-day-picker/moment';

import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';

const DayPickerRange = () => {
  const [days, setDays] = useState({
    from: new Date(),
    to: new Date(today.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  });

  function showFromMonth() {
    const { from, to } = days;
    if (!from) {
      return;
    }
    if (moment(to).diff(moment(from), 'months') < 2) {
      // this.to.getDayPicker().showMonth(from);
      to.getDayPicker().showMonth(from);
    }
  }

  const handleFromChange = from => {
    // Change the from date and focus the "to" input field
    setDays({ from, to }, showFromMonth);
  };

  const handleToChange = to => {
    setDays({ from, to });
  };

  const { from, to } = days;

  const modifiers = {
    start: from,
    end: to
  };

  return (
    <div className="InputFromTo">
      <DayPickerInput
        value={from}
        placeholder="From"
        format="LL"
        formatDate={formatDate}
        parseDate={parseDate}
        dayPickerProps={{
          utc: true,
          selectedDays: [from, { from, to }],
          disabledDays: [{ before: new Date() }],
          toMonth: to,
          month: to,
          modifiers,
          numberOfMonths: 12,
          onDayClick: () => to.getInput().focus()
        }}
        onDayChange={handleFromChange}
      />
      <span className="InputFromTo-to">
        <DayPickerInput
          ref={el => {
            days.to = el;
          }}
          value={to}
          placeholder="To"
          format="LL"
          formatDate={formatDate}
          parseDate={parseDate}
          dayPickerProps={{
            selectedDays: [from, { from, to }],
            disabledDays: [{ before: new Date() }],
            modifiers,
            month: from,
            fromMonth: from,
            numberOfMonths: 12,
            utc: true
          }}
          onDayChange={handleToChange}
        />
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DayPickerRange;
```

Comment: Possibly this is just a problem of using an old version of `days` in the `showFromMonth` method, since that is using the current version of `days`, while `handleFromChange` will receive the next version of `from`.

Comment: @HenryWoody - Thank you for responding, Could you please help with the snippet

Comment: Is the issue just that when the component first mounts that the year is wrong? Or is still wrong if you select another date?

Comment: Hi user, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things, you need to figure out / take into consideration while converting class based component to functional component.

Don't initialize your state with `new Date()`,

```
const [days, setDays] = useState({
  from: new Date(),
  to: new Date(today.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
});
```

Date format of `new Date()` and date format of your `DayPickerInput` is not same. So you need to keep it as `undefined` / convert the `new Date()` to format your `DayPickerInput` understands.

```
const [days, setDays] = useState({
  from: undefined,
  to: undefined
});
```

Another thing is, `setState` in class based component and functional component work a bit differently. `setState` in functional component don't have callback.

This `setState` is a bit wrong,

```
const handleFromChange = from => {
  // Change the from date and focus the "to" input field
  setDays({ from, to }, showFromMonth);
};

const handleToChange = to => {
  setDays({ from, to });
};
```

Here `showFromMonth` as callback will not work. You need a separate `useEffect` hook which will listen to state change and run side-effect / callback accordingly,

```
const handleFromChange = from => {
  // Change the from date and focus the "to" input field
  //This is functional setState which will only update `from` value
  setDays(days => ({
     ...days,
     from
  }));
};

const handleToChange = to => {
  //This is functional setState which will only update `to` value
  setDays(days => ({
    ...days,
    to
  }));
};

//This is useEffect hook which will run only when `to` value changes
useEffect(()=>{
  showFromMonth();
},[days.to, showFromMonth])
```

You have provided `ref` to your second date picker,

```
ref={el => {
    days.to = el;
}}
```

You should create a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) variable separately and not directly use state as `ref`.

```
let toInput = React.createRef();


ref={el => {
   toInput = el;
}}
```

I have made some modifications to your code according to [actual code](http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/input-from-to/) you provided in question.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xx5e4g)

Comment: Thank you for the solution, still see issues, once the dates are selected, the calendar defaults to previous year. It's replicable in your demo as well

Comment: @user12133234, the issue is because you have set `numberOfMonths: 12,` so when you choose `to` date and after that try to re select `from` date you will always see 12 months back from the `to` date. For example, if you choose `from` date as `September 28, 2019` and `to` date `October 1, 2019`, and after that try to reselect `from` date you will get last 12 months back from `October 1, 2019`. **It's your setting only and not a issue.** If you want to get rid out of this, you need to set `numberOfMonths: 2,`. Check the demo again, I have updated it.